# Derivation of the quantization of the EM field in a dielectrics

Tags: electromagnetism, operators, quantum-electrodynamics, commutator, dielectric

I'm currently studying the quantization of the EM field in a dielectric medium and trying to understand the quantization scheme of Huttner and Barnett (1992, see Phys. Rev. A 46, 4306). The system consists of a field part $H_{em}$, a matter part $H_{mat}$ (includes polarization and reservoir for losses), and an interaction part $H_{int}$.

In section III, they firstly diagonalize the Hamiltonian $H_{mat}$. They finally obtain
\begin{equation}
H_{mat} = \int d^3k \int_0^\infty d\omega B^\dagger (\vec k, \omega)B(\vec k, \omega),
\end{equation} where
\begin{align}
B(\vec k,\omega) = \alpha_0(\omega)b(\vec k) + \beta_0(\omega)b^\dagger(-\vec k) + \int_0^\infty d\omega^\prime\bigl[\alpha_1(\omega, \omega^\prime)b_{\omega^\prime}(\vec k) + \beta_1(\omega, \omega^\prime)b_{\omega^\prime}^\dagger(-\vec k)\bigr].
\end{align}

$b(\vec k)$ and $b_\omega(\vec k)$ denote the annihilation operators for the polarization field and the reservoir field, respectively. They satisfy the usual commutation relations:

\begin{align}
[b(\vec k), b^\dagger (\vec k^\prime)] &= \delta (\vec k - \vec k^\prime) \\
[b_\omega (\vec k), b_{\omega^\prime}^\dagger (\vec k^\prime) ]&= \delta (\vec k - \vec k^\prime) \delta (\omega - \omega^\prime).
\end{align}

Now to my problem: in Appendix A, the coefficients $\alpha_0(\omega)$, $\beta_0(\omega)$, $\alpha_1(\omega, \omega^\prime)$, and $\beta_1 (\omega, \omega^\prime)$ are derived via the eigenoperator equation

\begin{equation}
[B(\vec k, \omega), H_{mat}] = \hbar \omega B(\vec k, \omega),
\end{equation}

where $H_{mat}$ is explicitly given by

\begin{align}
H_{mat} = \int d^3k \biggl[\hbar \tilde{\omega_0} b^\dagger (\vec k) b(\vec k) + \int_0^\infty d\omega \hbar \omega b_\omega^\dagger (\vec k) b_\omega (\vec k) + \\
\frac{\hbar}{2} \int_0^\infty d\omega V(\omega)\bigl(b^\dagger(-\vec k) + b(\vec k)\bigr)\bigl(b_\omega^\dagger (-\vec k) + b_\omega(\vec k)\bigr).
\end{align}

$V(\omega)$ is related to the coupling, and the only restriction is that the analytical continuation of $|V(\omega)|^2$ to negative frequencies should be an odd function. If one calculates this commutator, one should obtain a system of linear equations for the coefficients, namely:

\begin{align}
\alpha_0(\omega) \omega = \alpha_0 (\omega) \tilde{\omega_0} + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty d\omega^\prime \bigl[\alpha_1(\omega, \omega^\prime)V(\omega^\prime) - \beta_1(\omega, \omega^\prime)V^*(\omega^\prime)\bigr], \\
\beta_0(\omega) \omega = -\beta_0 (\omega) \tilde{\omega_0} + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty d\omega^\prime \bigl[\alpha_1(\omega, \omega^\prime)V(\omega^\prime) - \beta_1(\omega, \omega^\prime)V^*(\omega^\prime)\bigr], \\
\alpha_1(\omega, \omega^\prime)\omega = \frac{1}{2}[\alpha_0(\omega) - \beta_0(\omega)]V^*(\omega^\prime)
+ \alpha_1(\omega, \omega^\prime)\omega^\prime, \\
\beta_1(\omega, \omega^\prime)\omega = \frac{1}{2}[\alpha_0(\omega) - \beta_0(\omega)]V(\omega^\prime) - \beta_1(\omega, \omega^\prime)\omega^\prime.
\end{align}

The problem is that I really don't know why those complex conjugates of $V(\omega)$ do show up. Is anyone into this topic and can maybe explain why those $V^*(\omega)$ do appear? Many thanks in advance!